# Обрезается картинка в слайде Slick Slider

Tags: css, вёрстка, slider, z-index

Есть стилизованный slick-slider где картинка должна выходить за верхнюю границу:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
При этом для .slick-list у меня задан фон(который фиксированный, пролистывается только содержимое - текст, картинка и кнопка):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Как сделать, чтобы картинка не обрезалась?

Comment: Картинки должны быть прямо в теле вопроса.

Comment: @KAGGDesign, отредактировал свой вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

Интересно для чего было ставить минус)

Подсказали в англоязычном Stack Overflow:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70396142/overflow-for-slick-slider-with-fixed-background-how-to-prevent-image-cropping-o?noredirect=1#comment124439538_70396142